# lateinit property recview has not been initialized

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

I have fragment which showing weather for 10 days  with getting geolocation city and show exactly weather for this city for 10 days.

I have problem  initialization with RecyclerView and Viewmodel.

Also I use Hilt to provide dependencies.

My goal is showing weather by location (already have permission) for 10 days.

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import db.entities.WeatherData


@HiltViewModel
interface ForecastViewmodel {
val dataforecast:LiveData<List<WeatherData>>
val city : LiveData<String>
val isRefreshing:LiveData<Boolean>

fun onRefresh()
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class ForecastViewmodelImpl(private val repository: ForecastRepository,
                            private val day: Day

                            ) : ForecastViewmodel,
    ViewModel(){

    override val dataforecast = MutableLiveData<List<WeatherData>>()
    override val city = MutableLiveData(day.city)
    override val isRefreshing = MutableLiveData(true)


    init {
        loadForecast()
    }

    private fun loadForecast() {
        isRefreshing.value = true
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val data = repository.getForecast(day.days)
             Timber.d("size is ${data}")
            }catch (e:Exception){
Timber.e(e)
            }
            isRefreshing.value = false
        }
    }

    override fun onRefresh() = loadForecast()

    private fun Forecastday.toWeatherData() = WeatherData(
        date = date,
        temp = "${temp.roundToInt()}℃"
    )
}
```

---

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.testtaskweatherappkevychsol.R
import db.entities.WeatherData

class WeatherRecView:RecyclerView.Adapter<WeatherRecView.WeatherHolder>() {
    var listweather = emptyList<WeatherData>()
    class WeatherHolder(view:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): WeatherHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.daily_weather_layout,
            parent,false)
        return WeatherHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: WeatherHolder,
        position: Int
    ) {
       holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Dateitem).text = listweather[position].date
        holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tempitem).text = listweather[position]
            .temp.toString()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return listweather.size
    }
    fun addlistintoUI(list: List<WeatherData>){
        listweather = list

    }
}
```

---

```
data class WeatherData(
    val temp:String,
    val date:String
)
```

---

```
import RecyclerView.WeatherRecView
import Viewmodel.ForecastViewmodel
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.testtaskweatherappkevychsol.R
import com.example.testtaskweatherappkevychsol.databinding.FragmentWeatherBinding
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint


@AndroidEntryPoint
class WeatherAtTheLifeMomentFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_weather){
    lateinit var recview:WeatherRecView
  private var binding : FragmentWeatherBinding? = null
 lateinit var  viewmodel:ForecastViewmodel




    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = FragmentWeatherBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        this.binding = binding
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
with(binding){
    this!!.refreshbt.setOnClickListener { viewmodel.isRefreshing }
    containerlistweather.adapter = recview
   containerlistweather.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(containerlistweather.context,
        (containerlistweather
       .layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).orientation))

    with(viewmodel){
dataforecast.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { recview.listweather = it }
       City.text = city.toString()
    }
}
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        binding = null
    }
}
```

---

Comment: You should initialize your `recview` adapter like this `recview = WeatherRecView()` in `onViewCreated` before you start using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lateinit property recview has not been initialized
```

you are getting this issue as you are trying to access lateinit property `recview` without initialising it

in `WeatherAtTheLifeMomentFragment`

From

```
containerlistweather.adapter = recview
```

To

```
recview = WeatherRecView() // initialise recview variable by creating instance of your adapter
containerlistweather.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context) // not sure you have set layout manager in your xml so just adding it in your code as it is necessary to use
containerlistweather.adapter = recview
```

Also you have create method `addlistintoUI` in `WeatherRecView` class so use it and make below mentioned changes to load your data

in `WeatherAtTheLifeMomentFragment` class

From

```
dataforecast.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { recview.listweather = it }
```

To

```
dataforecast.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { recview.addlistintoUI(it) }
```

in `WeatherRecView` class

From

```
fun addlistintoUI(list: List<WeatherData>){
        listweather = list

    }
```

To

````
fun addlistintoUI(list: List<WeatherData>){
        listweather.addAll(list)
        notifyDataSetChanged()

    }
    ```
````